# How to Create a Custom Loading page in ionic 2

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, ionic2, hybrid-mobile-app

Ionic 2 default loading page is src/index.html. I want to change it to my own custom.html with working app.component.ts. As I have already tried doing it by changing the content-src tag to custom .html file in config.xml file. But when I do that no function inside app.component.ts will execute in other words control will not enter inside it at all. I don't want to try this http://www.joshmorony.com/how-to-create-a-custom-loading-component-in-ionic-2/ as this is not for ionic 2.

So please suggest me how can I change my default loading page i,e index.html to custom page.

Comment: what is the output you need. so far what you have tried need some code

Comment: The starting page of the app will be index.html by default. But I want starting page to be channel.html in my case. As I'm converting my pre written website code to IOS app, many dependencies have been already set to channel.html. So I want to channel.html to appear on app load not index.html ...

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest solution will be to place the content of your `custom.html` inside the `index.html` in between the `<my-app></my-app>` tags. The content that is defined here will only be shown untill the component `<my-app>` has been loaded.

Here is an example I use myself

**index.html**

```
<body>    
  <my-app>
    <!-- loading page-->
    <div class="row" style="background-color: black; text-align: center;">
        <img src="images/loading.gif" style="width: auto; height: 100%;"/>
    </div>
  </my-app>
</body>
```

This will display my `loading.gif` fullscreen on a black background.

*(styles placed inline so I didn't have to add in a stylesheet).*

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I have some Javascript and other code dependencies which already use custom.html ... for my future enhancement of my project it is good only if I have my custom.html ... So i want to load that on page load ... Is there any choice??

Comment: you could try to include your `custom.html` in between the `<my-app>` tags. Not sure how fast the javascript file is loaded and `w3IncludeHtml()` are. Check out guide here http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp